# Use switch operator with Firebase in react Drawer Navigatoin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, authentication

I have a drawer navigation in which I would only like to show certain screens based on a condition from firebase realtime database, but the function below is returning undefined. This is in expo React Native.

```
function getType(){

  Firebase.database().ref('allTeachers/' + Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/name')
  .once('value').then(function(snapshot){

    return snapshot.exists()
  })
}
```

and this is the navigator where I want to use the result of this function. The navigator is inside a functional component

```
!user ? (
            <Drawer.Screen name = "Log In" component={SignUp}/>
            ):getType() ?(

              <>
              <Drawer.Screen name = "Session Creation" component={TeacherSession} />
              <Drawer.Screen name = "Activate Session" component={StartSession} />
              <Drawer.Screen name = "Teacher Details" component={TeacherDetails} />
              <Drawer.Screen name = "Sign Out" component={SignOut} />

              </>
            ):(

                <>
                <Drawer.Screen name = "Student Details" component={StudentDetails} />

                <Drawer.Screen name = "Sign Out" component={SignOut} />
                </>
            )}
```

I want to be able to switch between the two cases based on whether the path exists or not, can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function getType() doesn't have a return statement, so it will never return a value. To achieve what you want you will have to manage that asyncronously. A simple way of accomplish that is using a state.

Assuming that the component that holds your navigator is a functional one, the following should work

```
const [exists, setExists] = useState(false);

function getType(){

  Firebase.database().ref('allTeachers/' + Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/name')
  .once('value').then(function(snapshot){

    setExists(snapshot.exists());
  })
}

React.useEffect(() => {
    getType();
}, []);
```

...

```
!user ? (
            <Drawer.Screen name = "Log In" component={SignUp}/>
            ):exists ?(

              <>
              <Drawer.Screen name = "Session Creation" component={TeacherSession} />
              <Drawer.Screen name = "Activate Session" component={StartSession} />
              <Drawer.Screen name = "Teacher Details" component={TeacherDetails} />
              <Drawer.Screen name = "Sign Out" component={SignOut} />

              </>
            ):(

                <>
                <Drawer.Screen name = "Student Details" component={StudentDetails} />

                <Drawer.Screen name = "Sign Out" component={SignOut} />
                </>
            )}
```